# How to implement Vertical pagecontrol using Swift?

Tags: swift

I've tried using "pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2)" , but all xcode spits out the error: " 'double' is not convertible to 'CGFloat' "

Could somebody spread some light on this please?

Comment: Right, `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation()` takes a `CGFloat`, not a `Double`. You need to convert `M_PI_2` to `CGFloat`.